# Configuration page disappeared after disabling Magento extensions

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration

I have disabled all of the **Magento extensions** from **System > Configuration > Advanced**. Now I can't see anything in the **Configuration tab.** I have attached the screenshot below:

[image]

What is the issue? How I can solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to sign out and sign back in?

Comment: Damn. It's even worse. Now I can't see the login page. Can you please inform me what to do? I am a newbie in here.

Comment: Did you check your error logs? Normally a white page means that there is an error somewhere. If you fix the error in the logs, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the modules again, i guess you disabled some needed modules.

Go to your database and execute:

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output%'
```

This will show you where the output is disabled (value = 1). Make sure that the value for advanced/modules_disable_output/Mage_Admin is 0.
Clean your cache afterwards.

If that doesn't work try to enable more modules until it works again

Comment: Is it possible to enable the modules from the ftp under app/etc/module folder?

Comment: When you change the setting in de administration, Magento saves that setting to the database. So the database setting will overwrite the setting in the app/etc/module folder. You don't have access to the database?

Comment: Sorry. Currently I don't have the access to the database. It's my client's site :(

Comment: The connection details are in app/etc/local.xml. Try connecting. Else write a script that connects to that database and enables the modules again. Be carefull of course

Comment: How to do that? I found the local.xml file. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Go to ‘/app/etc/’ directory and open the file ‘local.xml’.
            
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    1
                
            
Here you can see all the data u need:
see host, username, password and the dbname nodes in the xml structure.

Comment: Yes, I found that. But the problem is I don't have cpanel access. I only have the access in ftp and Magento Admin(Which is blank now). Is there any other way to active the necessary modules from the ftp?

Comment: http://www.aschroder.com/2010/05/installing-a-magento-extension-manually-via-ftp-or-ssh/     maybe this helps